Video streaming with django from jellyfin
I made a streaming application with django from a jellyfin server, I use video js to play my video media. the problem is that when I try to play videos that are more than 1 hour long and longer it takes crazy time it seems that the video is first downloaded and then played and what's more I can't advance the media and put in the position I want, I first suspected a video js option called preload, so I tried the values ​​'none', 'metadata' and 'auto', but nothing there Actually, a colleague gave me a guess that maybe django doesn't support this kind of functionality! Can anyone confirm this? what could be the solution with django
for example this is my function to get an episode type movie:
views.py
def episode_detail(request, episode_id):
    user_id = request.session.get('jellyfin_user_id')
    access_token = request.session.get('jellyfin_access_token')

    if not user_id or not access_token:
        return redirect('jellyfin_login')

    # try:
    #     user = JellyfinUser.objects.get(jellyfin_user_id=user_id)
    # except JellyfinUser.DoesNotExist:
    #     return redirect('jellyfin_login')

    headers = {
        'X-Emby-Token': settings.JELLYFIN_API_KEY
    }

    episode_url = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Users/{user_id}/Items/{episode_id}"
    episode_response = requests.get(episode_url, headers=headers)

    if episode_response.status_code != 200:
        return render(request, 'error.html', context={'error': 'Unable to fetch episode details'})

    episode = episode_response.json()

    if episode['Type'] == 'Movie':

        people = episode.get('People', [])
        if people is None:
            people = []

        genres_url = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Genres?ParentId={episode_id}"
        genres_response = requests.get(genres_url, headers=headers)
        genres = genres_response.json().get('Items', []) if genres_response.status_code == 200 else []
        episode['Genres'] = [genre['Name'] for genre in genres]

        studio_url = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Studios?ParentId={episode_id}"
        studio_response = requests.get(studio_url, headers=headers)
        studios = studio_response.json().get('Items', []) if studio_response.status_code == 200 else []
        episode['Studios'] = [studio['Name'] for studio in studios]

        directors = [person['Name'] for person in people if person['Type'] == 'Director']
        episode['Directors'] = directors

        actors = []
        for person in people:
            if person['Type'] == 'Actor':

                actor_image_url = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Persons/{person['Name']}/Images/Primary"
                actor_image_url_response = requests.get(actor_image_url, headers=headers)

                if actor_image_url_response.status_code == 200:
                    person['ImageURL'] = actor_image_url
                else:
                    person['ImageURL'] = static("library/images/default/default-user.jpg")

                actor_info = {
                    'name': person['Name'],
                    'role': person['Role'],
                    'image': person['ImageURL'],
                    'id': person['Id'],
                }
                actors.append(actor_info)

        episode['Actors'] = actors

        writers = [person['Name'] for person in people if person['Type'] == 'Writer']
        episode['Writers'] = writers

        producers = [person['Name'] for person in people if person['Type'] == 'Producer']
        episode['Producers'] = producers

        similar_url = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Items/{episode_id}/Similar"
        similar_response = requests.get(similar_url, headers=headers)
        similar_episodes = similar_response.json().get('Items', []) if similar_response.status_code == 200 else []
        for item in similar_episodes:
            item['ImageURL'] = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Items/{item['Id']}/Images/Primary"
        episode['SimilarEpisodes'] = similar_episodes

        episode['VideoURL'] = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Videos/{episode['Id']}/stream"
        episode['ImageURL'] = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Items/{episode['Id']}/Images/Primary"
        episode['BackdropURL'] = f"{settings.JELLYFIN_URL}/Items/{episode['Id']}/Images/Backdrop"
        episode['CommunityRating'] = episode.get('CommunityRating', 'N/A')
        episode['Overview'] = episode.get('Overview', 'Aucune description disponible')

        episode['Duration'] = format_duration(episode['RunTimeTicks'])
            print("NO FILE")

    user_data = episode.get('UserData', {})
    if user_data is None:
        user_data = {}

    episode['IsFavorite'] = user_data.get('IsFavorite', False)

    print(episode['Type'])

    return render(request, 'episode_detail.html', context={'episode': episode})


and this is my episode_detail.html:
episode_detail.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} {{ episode.Name }} {% endblock %}

{% block style %}

        <!-- My Styles -->

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container mb-5">

    {% if episode.Type == 'Movie' %}

    <div class="row">

        <!-- AFFICHE DU FILM -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="{{ episode.ImageURL }}" class="img-fluid movie-poster shadow-lg" alt="{{ episode.Name }}">
        </div>

        <!-- INFOS DU FILM -->
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <h1 class="text-white">{{ episode.Name }}</h1>

            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="production-year">{{ episode.ProductionYear }}</span>
                <span class="duration">{{ episode.Duration }}</span>
                <span class="note-commu">
                    <span>{{ episode.CommunityRating|floatformat:1 }}</span>
                    <span class="blue-star"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></span>
                </span>
            </div>

            <!-- SYNOPSIS DU FILM -->
            {% if episode.Overview %}
            <div class="mt-3">
                <h4 class="section-title"><b>Synopsis</b></h4>
                <p>{{ episode.Overview }}</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

            <!-- DETAILS DU FILM -->
            <div class="mt-3">

                {% if episode.Genres or episode.Studios or episode.Directors or episode.Actors %}
                    <h4 class="section-title"><b>Details</b></h4>
                {% endif %}

                {% if episode.Genres %}<p><strong>Genre:</strong> {{ episode.Genres|join:", " }}</p>{% endif %}
                {% if episode.Studios %}<p><strong>Studios:</strong> {{ episode.Studios|join:", " }}</p>{% endif %}
                {% if episode.Directors %}<p><strong>Réalisateurs :</strong> {{episode.Directors|join:", " }}</p>{% endif %}
                {% if episode.Writers %}<p><strong>Scénaristes :</strong> {{episode.Writers|join:", " }}</p>{% endif %}
                {% if episode.Producers %}<p><strong>Producteurs:</strong> {{ episode.Producers|join:", " }}</p>{% endif %}
                {% if episode.Actors_name %}<p><strong>Acteurs:</strong> {{ episode.Actors_name|join:", " }}</p>{% endif %}
            </div>


            <!-- SECTION VIDEO DU FILM -->
            <div class="mt-5">
                <video
                        id="my-movie-video"
                        class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered vjs-fluid vjs-fill"
                        controls
                        preload="none"
                        poster="{{ episode.BackdropURL }}"
                        data-setup="{}"
                >
                    <source src="{{ episode.VideoURL }}" type="video/mp4" />
                    <source src="{{ episode.VideoURL }}" type="video/webm" />
                    <source src="{{ episode.VideoURL }}" type="video/avi" />
                    <source src="{{ episode.VideoURL }}" type="video/mkv" />
                    <p class="vjs-no-js">
                        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
                        web browser that
                        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                    </p>
                </video>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}


Django's default server isn't optimized for streaming large video files.
As for seeking videos, you would need to implement HTTP Range Requests.
Without any code snippet is hard to tell what you need to change.

I edited with more information


"It takes crazy time it seems that the video is first downloaded and then played"

Check that your MP4s have their metadata at the front (instead of back of file). You can use this site to check an MP4 (scroll down to MP4 atom locations section).
If it says "Not optimized" then the metadata is at back (and also a full download is needed).
You can fix using a tool like FFmpeg or even search Google for: MP4 moov Fast start fix advice.

"I can't advance the media and put in the position I want, ""

When you provide bytes yourself (through streaming) then you must handle seeking yourself. This means listen for a seek event (triggered by HTML5 video tag) and provide new bytes for that seek point. Your MP4 must a fragmented MP4 in order to easily seek via bytes streaming. When your app is given a seek point (in seconds) then you calculate which file (if separated by time) or which bytes range (if all video duration is inside one file) is needed to be read. Your streamer now sends those bytes instead. The bytes would be an MP4 fragment representing the data for the requested "seek-to" time.
